# Visual Studio add-on gallery?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-addins, add-on

i'm hoping to find some add-ons for Visual Studio to address some specific usability issues. Is there a Visual Studio addons gallery that contains a huge dumping ground of addons that every person, company, yahoo and hick have created?

Kind of like [Vista Sidebar Gadget gallery](http://vista.gallery.microsoft.com/vista/SideBar.aspx), but for addons.

Kind of like [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com), but for addons.

Is [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.com) it?

---

Not that it's important to my question, but *some* of the IDE functionality i was hoping to see addressed through addons:

- tabs are placed in chronological open order
- renaming a control renames attached event handlers
- deleting all code from an event handler deletes and unhooks the event handler
- deleting an event handler unhooks it
- rearrange code so private, protected and public methods and grouped. Properties and events are grouped. Private variables are grouped.
- analyse for `using` lint
- controls that have been cut/pasted have their event handlers functional
- [full](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfz7zwas.aspx) support for [B.R.I.E.F. bookmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brief_(text_editor)) ([found it](http://vadikv.googlepages.com/numberedbookmarks))
- /// automatically adds thrown exceptions
- /// comments are rendered on the item their declared for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for [this](http://www.visualstudiogallery.com/?s_kwcid=visual%20studio%20plugins|2461732986)

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio Gallery is it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/)?